# jquery dynamic id and rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Upon clicking a button with dynamic id, I want to put `dst.district` into a textbox with id `district`.
I have written following code, but it's currently not working.

```
<input name="" type="text" class="dist1" id="district">
   <% @districts.each do |dst|%>                         
       <div id="dist_<%= dst.id%>" class="districtname"><%= dst.district %></div>                        
       <input id="select_<%= dst.id%>" type="button" value="Select" class="gbutton" />
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#select_<%= dst.id %>").click({
                $("#district").val("<%= dst.district %>");
    });
   </script>                        
   <%end%>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow this code:

```
<input name="" type="text" class="dist1" id="district">
<% @districts.each do |dst|%>
  <li>                    
   <div class="districtname"><%= dst.district %></div>                        
       <input name="select" id="select_<%= dst.id%>" type="button" value="Select" class="gbutton" />
  </li>                    
<%end%>
```

and

```
$(".gbutton").click(function(){
        var getID = this.id.split("_");
        console.log(getID[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the class instead of the id? It may work. Try it and let me know.

```
<input name="select" id="select_<%= dst.id%>" type="button" value="Select" class="gbutton" />
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(".gbutton").click(function(){    
                  $("#district").val('the value you want into the textbox');                                      
            });
          </script>
```